# Account of the cloud used by CloudKit

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit

Sorry for maybe a silly question. I want my app to use iCloud for backing up and synchronising user's data, assuming that CloudKit works with user's cloud. However it may not be the case.

I have two cloud accounts: personal and developer's ones. My macOS is logged to the personal iCloud account, so I expected my macOS app to use it. However CloudKit Dashboard shows cloud containers for the developer's account instead.

Also [iCloud design guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html) says "*CloudKit provides a way to store data as records in a database that users of your app can share*" which implies that the cloud data represent a single instance for all users.

So, which cloud: user's, developer's, or a separate one (designed especially for app containers) is used by CloudKit? It case a separate cloud it used does it count as a developer's storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudKit container for your app contains two databases; A public database that is accessible to all users of your app and a private database that is only accessible to the current user.

Individual records in the private database can be shared with another user via a `CKShare`.

Data that is stored in the public database comes from your app's storage allocation; the amount of storage you get for free depends on the number of app installations.

Data that is stored in the private database is stored in the user's iCloud storage and counts against their storage allocation.

From the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH2-SW3) document

> An app has access to both a public and private database in each container. The *public database* is for storing user and app data that is shared between all instances of the app. By default, all users can read the public database, but they need to enter iCloud credentials to write to the public database. There’s a *private database* for each user of your app, but the app only has access to the private database of the current user. The user has to enter iCloud credentials for the app to read and write to the private database.

Information is also available on [CloudKit Overview](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/) page - Check the footnotes at the bottom; private storage comes from the user's free 5GB allowance (they may purchase more). Public storage comes from your app's allowance.

Comment: I mark it as an answer. However I would like to get a reference to Apple documentation  confirming that.

Comment: Thanks indeed. The actual quotation is: "iCloud provides users 5 GB of free storage for private data and documents with an option to upgrade their iCloud storage plan up to 2 TB"